# PayPal won't accept every credit/debit card - Smart Buttons Checkout

Tags: paypal, payment, credit-card, countries

I'm using PayPal Samart Buttons which offers me two possiblities: pay with a PayPal account and use a credit/debit card.

The problem is that PayPal seems to not accept payments with credit/debit card from some countries as I created a few personal accounts (sandbox) and only some of them work. The error I get is:

> Something went wrong. We'll take you back to checkout so you can try
>   again.

It seems like only payments with PayPal accounts are available for some countries. How can I accept credit/debit cards from all countries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which countries are you concerned about, exactly?

If you want a solution that accepts credit/debit cards from all countries, you will likely need a full gateway solution or merchant account. Which ones are available to you will depend on which country you are in, and your business history and credit.

Comment: I see, that is what I tought. I have noticed it does not accept credit/debt card payments from some countries located in South America and Europe. Perhaps I need to apply for a Merchant account as you said, like PayPal pro or something. By the way, this "full gateway solution" you talk about, is this like direct communication with the bank or another payment gateway solution like PayPal?

Comment: PayPal Pro is an example, but that's available in very few countries. The Braintree Gateway is another example, available in a few more countries. Typically a gateway is desirable because this provides a standardized interface for communicating with the banks that provide merchant accounts that do the processing. But what options are available to you will depend very much on what country you are in, and your business credit (not all businesses qualify for all types of processing)

Comment: Smart Payment Buttons is convenient because it is available to businesses almost anywhere in the world, with very little setup -- but its behavior will vary somewhat depending on the buyer's country.

Comment: I see, i took a look at Brantree and it seems to be accept all or almost all credit/debit cards from almost all countries as well. Thank you, @Preston PHX

Comment: Yes that's what made me sad, hahaha. Samrt Payment Buttons very fast and user-friendly but I have noticed it does not work with a few countries...maybe beucase It's sandbox...I don't know.

Comment: Thank you once again. Besides that, everything is working OK. Yes, indeed I have tried with BR and did not work.

Comment: @PrestonPHX wait, what? I'm updating my DoExpressCheckout/SOAP implementation to use the Smart Credit/Button stuff (incl Venmo, PayLater), but the javascript SDK smart stuff absolutely has to accept payment from each and every one of the countries you listed, I have customers in all of them! Are the JS SDK buttons limited? That's a showstopper. Why wouldn't they cover everything the existing still-live SOAP APIs do?

Comment: The buttons work everywhere, it's just a matter of whether local regulations and processors permit the inline form.  MX does allow it now, not sure of any other changes.  You can test in the sandbox with `&buyer-country=XX` if you need to see the behavior, but it's not important, people can pay in the popup if an iframe doesn't expand

Comment: @PrestonPHX any chance you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919648/paypal-rest-token-request-api-paypal-com-ok-api-m-fails ---- observed behavior really shouldn't be happening!