# PayPal REST token request: api.paypal.com OK, api-m fails

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

**Addendum 2**:The Mozilla behavior is specific to which host the URL resolves to; I've added curl script showing this at the end of the Question.

Addendum: This had gone away 8 hours later or so, and worked for several days. But a week later, I re-run the page just to check, and it is failing repeatedly again: api.paypal works, api-m.paypal doesn not.

I receive different results requesting a live-site access token from api-m.paypal.com and api.paypal.com. If I make the request to api.paypal.com, it works and a token is returned. If I request it from api-m.paypal.com, I receive a 403 Forbidden error. How is this possible? In general, and for token requests, the documentation seems to use api and api-m interchangeably. What's the difference between the two and what calls should be routed to api vs api-m? When I'm running my whole store on the sandbox, *everything* goes to api-m and works fine. In a test program that just requests tokens repeatedly, sequencing through api, api-m, api.sandbox, and api-m.sandbox --- only api-m fails, the other 3 cases are good. I saw an api vs api-m discussion once but can't find it again; pretty sure it didn't mention this!

```php
<?php

include("../_private/ppinfo.php");

header('Content-type: text/plain');
$sandbox = 0;
echo "sandbox $sandbox rv " . GetNewPPToken($sandbox) . "\n";
$sandbox = 1;
echo "sandbox $sandbox rv " . GetNewPPToken($sandbox) . "\n";
$sandbox = 2;
echo "sandbox $sandbox rv " . GetNewPPToken($sandbox) . "\n";
$sandbox = -1;
echo "sandbox $sandbox rv " . GetNewPPToken($sandbox) . "\n";
$sandbox = 0;
echo "sandbox $sandbox rv " . GetNewPPToken($sandbox) . "\n";
$sandbox = -1;
echo "sandbox $sandbox rv " . GetNewPPToken($sandbox) . "\n";
$sandbox = 1;
echo "sandbox $sandbox rv " . GetNewPPToken($sandbox) . "\n";
$sandbox = 0;
echo "sandbox $sandbox rv " . GetNewPPToken($sandbox) . "\n";
$sandbox = 2;
echo "sandbox $sandbox rv " . GetNewPPToken($sandbox) . "\n";

// Get a paypal REST token to use for the rest of our transactions.
// See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/get-started/

function GetNewPPToken($sandbox) 
{
    global $G, $ppinfo;

    $headers = array(
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Accept-Language: en_US",
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        );
    if ($sandbox > 1)
    {
    $clid = $ppinfo['sb_acct'];
    $secret = $ppinfo['sb_secr'];
    $url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
    }
    else if ($sandbox > 0)
    {
    $clid = $ppinfo['sb_acct'];
    $secret = $ppinfo['sb_secr'];
    $url = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
    }
    else if ($sandbox < 0)
    {
    $clid = $ppinfo['acct'];
    $secret = $ppinfo['secr'];
    $url = "https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
    }
    else
    {
    $clid = $ppinfo['acct'];
    $secret = $ppinfo['secr'];
    $url = "https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
    };

    $cvt = "grant_type=client_credentials";
    $curl = newPPcurl($url, $cvt, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$clid:$secret");
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl) ;
    $json = json_decode($resp, true);

    if (0)
    {
    echo "response:\n";
    print_r($resp);
    echo "err:\n";
    print_r($err);
    echo "token '" . $ppinfo['token'] . "'\n";
    };

    $ppinfo['token'] = $json['access_token'];
    return ($ppinfo['token'] != '' ? 1 : 0);
}



function newPPcurl($url, $flds, $hdrs)
{
    $user_agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    if ($flds != '')
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $flds);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2); // or 2?
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pem);  // pem file name
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    if ($hdrs != "")
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $hdrs);

    return $curl;
}
```

Test output:

```
sandbox 0 rv 0
sandbox 1 rv 1
sandbox 2 rv 1
sandbox -1 rv 1
sandbox 0 rv 0
sandbox -1 rv 1
sandbox 1 rv 1
sandbox 0 rv 0
sandbox 2 rv 1
```

Here's some curl commands that show this behavior. When api-m.paypal.com resolves to 184.87.90.6, the token is fetched OK with the Mozilla agent (cmd #1). When the IP resolves to 151.101.1.35, the request fails for Mozilla (cmd#2), passes for curl (cmd#3). Note that you'll have to supply your own id:pwd strings to test.

```
curl -v https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
    --user-agent "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)" \
    --resolve api-m.paypal.com:443:184.87.90.6 \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "<id:pwd>" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
curl -v https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
    --user-agent "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)" \
    --resolve api-m.paypal.com:443:151.101.1.35 \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "<id:pwd>" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
curl -v https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
    --user-agent "curl/7.55.1" \
    --resolve api-m.paypal.com:443:151.101.1.35 \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "<id:pwd>" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior with command line curl (no PHP) ?  Or in PHP with a library such as Guzzle?

Comment: Good idea, curl worked... right up until I set the user agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The PayPal REST token request's user-agent must be a curl identifier, such as "curl/7.55.1".** Using a Mozilla user agent causes 403 FORBIDDEN on api-m.paypal.com, though it will appear to work on api.paypal.com, api.sandbox.paypal.com, and api-m.sandbox.paypal.com

Comment: What user agent were you using? Testing with curl 7.64.1 and the flag `-A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"` to the url `https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token`, it works fine for me.

Comment: The one in the source above "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"

Comment: I see different responses based on what server the URL resolves to. Works OK w/Mozilla: 184.87.90.6..  Does not work: 151.101.1.35. I was able to verify with  curl ... --resolve. (Adding curl to Q above)

Comment: @PrestonPHX Playing with tracert, I found additional IP addresses that fail with Mozilla, pass with Curl user-agent strings: 151.101.1.35  151.101.65.35 The one that passes with Mozilla is an akamai mirror, the ones that fail are api-m-fastly.glb.paypal.com addresses.

Comment: Interesting, it's only `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)` that fails, particularly due to the MSIE 5.01. That's quite an old user agent! Looks like MSIE must be at least 6 or above, but even that would be scary old.

Comment: Weird. That's an old user agent string back from my original SOAP implementation when it needed some user agent. It's not like any browser's really coming there anyway.  In any case, it may be worth noting in the docs that a curl user agent is suggested, and of course any behavioral difference between mirrors is a little concerning. It's been fine with curl so I'll move along. Thanks.

Comment: There are troubleshooting use cases where a browser does do the requests, so I was concerned, but no one will actually be using an old MSIE for that so it's fine :)